# Not able to install rpart.plot

Tags: r

Hi when I run the command in R

```
install.packages('rpart.plot')
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
```

package ‘rpart.plot’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: please use `install.packages("rpart.plot")`

Comment: Tried that but got the same error message

Comment: I just installed the package using the same command

Comment: have you installed `rpart` before this?

Comment: Yes I have done that.

Comment: can you check your R version

Comment: 3.0.2 is the version.

Comment: it `Depends: R (≥ 3.2.0), rpart (≥ 4.1-10)`

Comment: upgrade your R and it will work